# Cant figure this questiion out. Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is a homework question that been working on for awhile, but i cant seem to figure out the rest.

> Your program is going to calculate the price of some bags of coffee. 
>   You will first ask the user; how many bags of coffee do they want.
>   The price per bag is $5.50 each.  Your price must also include the
>   shipping of how many boxes this shipment will require.  There are
>   three size shipping boxes available.  A large box can hold 20 bags, a
>   medium box holds 10 bags, and a small box can hold up to 5 bags.  You
>   cannot ship large or medium boxes that are not full. (but small ones
>   can have 1-5 bags in them) The price of shipping per box is large =
>   $1.80, medium = $1.00, and small = $0.60 .  One final price change is
>   a possible discount.  Use the following chart to calculate the
>   discount off of the coffee price (NOT off the shipping).
>
> ```
> 0-24 bags    - no discount        
> 25-49 bags   – 5% discount
> 50-99 bags   – 10% discount       
> 100-149 bags – 15% discount
> 150-199 bags - 20% discount
> 200-299 bags - 25% discount
> 300 and up   - 30% discount
> ```
>
> Discount is not to be used on the boxes.  Use if statements or a
>   switch statement to get this done.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class discount {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello how are you? How many numberbags of coffee would you like?");

       double numberbag;
       double bag = 5.50;

       numberbag = key.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("Number of numberbags ordered: " + numberbag);
       double price = (numberbag * bag);    
       System.out.println("- $" + price);

   if (numberbag < 24 && numberbag > 0) {
      System.out.println("no discount: $" + price);
   }
   else if (numberbag < 49 && numberbag > 25) {
      System.out.println("5% discount: $" + price * .05);    
   }
   else if (numberbag < 99 && numberbag > 50) {
      System.out.println("10% discount: $" + price  * .10);    
   }
   else if (numberbag < 149 && numberbag > 100) {
      System.out.println("15% discount: $" + price * .15);    
   }
   else if (numberbag < 199 && numberbag > 150) {
      System.out.println("20% discount: $" + price * .20);    
   }
   else if (numberbag < 299 && numberbag > 200) {
      System.out.println("25% discount: $" + price * .25);    
   }
   else {
      System.out.println("30% discount: $" + price * .30);
   }
   double small = ;
   double medium = 10; 
   double large = 20;

   double sp = 0.60;
   double mp = 1.00;
   double lp = 1.80;

   double Rl = numberbag%large;
   double Rm = Rl%medium;
   double Rs = Rm%small;
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, but you should definitely reexamine the logic in your `if-else` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this

```
       if (numberbag < 24 && numberbag > 0) {
              System.out.println("no discount: $" + price);
           }
           else if (numberbag < 49 && numberbag > 25) {
              System.out.println("5% discount: $" + (price - (price * .05)));    
           }
           else if (numberbag < 99 && numberbag > 50) {
              System.out.println("10% discount: $" + (price - (price * .10)));    
           }
           else if (numberbag < 149 && numberbag > 100) {
              System.out.println("15% discount: $" + (price - (price * .15)));    
           }
           else if (numberbag < 199 && numberbag > 150) {
              System.out.println("20% discount: $" + (price - (price * .20)));    
           }
           else if (numberbag < 299 && numberbag > 200) {
              System.out.println("25% discount: $" + (price - (price * .25)));    
           }
           else {
              System.out.println("30% discount: $" + (price - (price * .30)));
           }
```

Comment: There are three size shipping boxes available. A large box can hold 20 bags, a medium box holds 10 bags, and a small box can hold up to 5 bags. You cannot ship large or medium boxes that are not full. (but small ones can have 1-5 bags in them) The price of shipping per box is large = $1.80, medium = $1.00, and small = $0.60 . ......... How can i add this to the code, i tried many things but couldnt figure it out

Comment: Make a method like this

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question about the boxes. 
Create a method like this

```
public static double calculateBoxes(int y) {
    int remainder = y%20;
    int bigBox = y/20;
    int remainder2 = remainder%10;
    int medBox = remainder/10;
    int remainder3 = remainder2%5;
    int smallBox = remainder2/5;

    if (remainder3 == 0){

    }
    else{
        smallBox++;
    }

    double boxPrice = (bigBox*1.80)+(medBox*1.00)+(smallBox*.60);

    return boxPrice;
}
```

Then call it from your main like this

calculateBoxes(numberBag)